# Gspread & Oauth2 on Python 3.4 - Oauth does not support indexing

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, gspread

I want to use gspread and since client authentication is outdated, I'm trying with Oauth2.  I'm new to both gspread & Oauth2.

Piecing together [from this basic Oauth2 example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) and [the gspread documentation](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) I have the most basic login function.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
CLIENT_ID = 'my id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'my secret key'
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id= CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret= CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/',
    redirect_uri='http://localhost:80')
gc = gspread.authorize(flow)
```

The problem is that I get this error.

> TypeError: 'OAuth2WebServerFlow' object does not support indexing

from the larger

> C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py:73: Warning: 
>               ClientLogin is deprecated:
>               https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps?csw=1
>
> ```
>         Authorization with email and password will stop working on April 20, 2015.
>
>         Please use oAuth2 authorization instead:
>         http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html
> ```
>
> """, Warning)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\family\Desktop\mygspread.py", line 13, in 
>       gc = gspread.authorize(flow)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 335, in authorize
>       client.login()
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 105, in login
>       data = {'Email': self.auth[0],
>   TypeError: 'OAuth2WebServerFlow' object does not support indexing

Since both are official scripts - one from google and the other from burnash, I'm not sure what to change.  I know the question is basic, but how do I log in with Python 3.4?

Comment: Basically Google has made an official announcement that "From April 20, 2015, the only way to access any Google API is through OAUTH 2.0"

Previously, we can access by giving our email and password. Currently it is depreciated. So, go with Burnash's one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OAUTH 2.0 using 2 ways.

1. Service account

> Calls Google API's on behalf of your application instead of an end
>   user

Follow [here](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) for more details:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('gspread-april-2cd … ba4.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Where is the money Lebowski?").sheet1
```

2. Web application

> Accessed by web browsers over the network

Follow [this blog](http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/#comment-2071255881) for more details

```
import requests, gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

def authenticate_google_docs():
    f = file(os.path.join('your-key-file.p12'), 'rb')
    SIGNED_KEY = f.read()
    f.close()
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('username@gmail.com', SIGNED_KEY, scope)

    data = {
        'refresh_token' : '<refresh-token-copied>',
        'client_id' : '<client-id-copied>',
        'client_secret' : '<client-secret-copied>',
        'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
    }

    r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data = data)
    credentials.access_token = ast.literal_eval(r.text)['access_token']

    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    return gc
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  If anyone else is interested, this is what I needed to do

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
json_key = json.load(open('Gspread-762ec21ac2c5.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email']
    , bytes(json_key['private_key']
    , 'utf-8')
    , scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open("mytestfile").sheet1
```